# Issue with maven-release-plugin while using with CircleCI

Tags: maven, circleci

I am trying to use maven-release-plugin to release to Nexus release repository and this is working fine, when I am running locally in my PC. However, when I have configured the same in my job in circleci i am getting the below error.

```html
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/circleci/repo && git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-724046220.commit pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/circleci/repo
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.414 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-11T17:00:30Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project : Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] *** Please tell me who you are.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Run
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
[ERROR]   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] to set your account's default identity.
[ERROR] Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] fatal: empty ident name (for <(null)>) not allowed
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I have used the below scm in my pom.xml (because of formatting issues i have not given the xml)

```html
<scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:organization/project.git</connection>
        <url>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:organization/project.git</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:organization/project.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>@{project.version}</tag>
</scm>
```

I am using the below command for calling in my job -

```html
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=${BUILD_VERSION_NUM} -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false -Dtag=${VERSION_NUM}
```

Any suggestion, why git-commit command is failing in circleci. Any specific setting I have to do.

Many thanks,
Sujit

Answer (score 1):

If you're pulling/pushing to a GitHub repo that's not the current one for the CircleCI build, you'd need to setup a deploy or user key: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/gh-bb-integration/#creating-a-github-user-key